# How to use web hooks for applying templates during the creation of work items

Tags: azure-devops, server, automation, webhooks, workitem

I would like to to automatically add data to multiple fields when creating new work item in Azure Devops boards
For example: when a user create new bug - the planned version field will be set automatically to lastest version available

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the **work item rule** feature to do this.

For example:

> **Conditions**
>
> **`When`** **`A work item is create ...`**
>
> **Actions**
>
> **`Then`** **`Set the value of ...`** **`{Field Name}`** **`to`** **`{Value}`**

[image]

This feature is available in all the customize processes (Inheritance process). For more details, you can reference the document "[**Add a rule to a work item type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops)".